# How to change the cursor hotspot in OS X 10.8.5 Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, mouse

The hotspot of the cursor is on the tip of the internal, black part.

When I enlarge the cursor, the white outline is enlarged as well, so the tip of the white outline and the inner tip of the black body get pretty far from one another. I keep clicking on the white tip (as it's the outermost tip, the "absolute" tip of the arrow).

I know it has always been like that on Macs, I know many of you love it that way. To me it's counter-intuitive (please don't debate this, it's my personal preference and I have found on a few forums that I'm not alone in this, so the answer could be useful to a number of people).

**Is there a way to change the cursor hotspot? For example by editing the cursor file and replacing the original one?** Where is the cursor file in OS X 10.8.5? Is there any (file as such), or is the cursor some OS method or whatever?

Or, as an alternative, to just download a different cursor (with the hotspot on the outermost tip) and replace the original system one?

Comment: I respect the personal preference, but out of curiosity: why does this bother you?

Comment: Here's why. I prefer a larger arrow - I can't explain why, I just like it bigger :-) Then the white tip and black tip get more away from one another - and when I have to click on something small, the white tip must be OUT of that area, you know, sticking out upper-left... in order for the black tip to point accurately. This often happens when I fast-forward YouTube videos, and that's a frequent operation. And it's just annoying... changin the hotspot shouldn't be too much of a difficult operation, for example what if I want my default cursor to be a crosshair? Or a finger? Or a banana? :-D

Comment: Not that I'm a very huge banana-lover though, arrow is quite fine... it's more a story about freedom and choice. And precision in clicking small items with a somewhat large arrow. Why be annoyed on a daily basis if you can tweak one file?

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you an answer you'll hate. You would have to batch change the .png of the all OS cursors in:

/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HiServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors

In the neighbourhood of a 100 pngs and adjusting singular pixels is what I see as the only option because there is no other way I can think of to adjust the 'active hotspot'

Comment: So there is a way of doing it after all :-) However, in this folder there is no arrow (the default cursor), do you happen to know where it might be?